# Notify when the binding of Dependency Property is changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to debug the Binding setup of a given dependency property.
At the beginning, I set the binding to the dependency property for a given source instance, with the following code:

```
var binding = new Binding(path);
            binding.Source = source;
            binding.Mode = twoWay ? BindingMode.TwoWay : BindingMode.OneWay;
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            binding.Converter = valueConverter;
            var bindingResult = BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ModelValueProperty, binding);

            var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, ModelValueProperty);
```

bindingExpression  is not null and the Status of binding is Active.
After some view manipulations, when I try to get bindingExpression it will null.
How do I catch the binding replacement or change on a given dependency property ?

**Edit:**
In another way, I want to know how to get notified when the bindingExpression changes its status from Active to Detached

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this property:

```
binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true
```

And register to the `SourceUpdated` event of the control you're bound to (in your case, it's `this` ):

```
        this.SourceUpdated += (s, args) =>
                                  {
                                      // Catch changes there
                                  };
```

**Alternatively**, you can catch the changes made directly on the `DependencyProperty`with a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`:

```
            var descriptor =  DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ModelValueProperty, typeof(YourType));
            descriptor.AddValueChanged(this, OnValueChanged);


            private void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //...
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the 1st solution I'm not in a FrameworkElement but in a simple DependencyObject. For the 2nd solution, I'm getting a null descriptor

Comment: The question is: why would you derive from DependencyObject rather than FrameworkElement, if you are writing a control?
Also for the descriptor, have you correctly set the type?

Comment: Actually ModelValueProperty is a part of a "decorator", a kind of view model derived from DependencyObject this decorator is used to add some logic to my business values.